# Ruby Monk - Understanding Inheritance - Alternate solution not accepted?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, testing, methods

I have been coding for three or four months (started in Python) and I am just getting into Ruby on account of Rails popularity.

To help build my understanding of the Ruby language, I have been going through the problems on Ruby Monk. The Ruby Primer: Ascent 1.1 - Understanding Inheritance course has the following problem:

*Write a method that takes a class and a subclass as arguments and returns a boolean regarding whether or not the subclass is an ancestor of the class.*

Here is what I came up with (note: Ruby Monk decided to go with spelling "klass" for "class"):

```
def is_ancestor?(klass, subclass)
  subclass.ancestors.map{ |ancestor| ancestor.to_s }.include? klass.to_s
end
```

This code passes all tests except for a special one that states `doesn't use any other methods to solve the problem (yes, there's a shortcut :))`.

I was really vexed as to how to solve this without using other methods, and so I looked at the proposed solution. Here is what Ruby Monk says that answer should be.

```
def is_ancestor?(klass, subclass)
  current_class = subclass
  while !current_class.superclass.nil? && current_class != klass
    current_class = current_class.superclass
  end
  current_class == klass
end
```

I understand this code. What I don't understand is why this code passes the test requirement of not using methods while my code doesn't. After all, the Ruby Monk proposed answer *does* use methods (see `!current_class.superclass.nil`).

Am I missing something here? Perhaps I don't really understand what a method is. Perhaps my code *does* work and is only failing because Ruby Monk is performing tests that match code 1:1.

Comment: maybe it's the `ancestors` method they don't want you to use. You could also shorten your code to `subclass.ancestors.include?(klass)`

Comment: Why don't you look how the test is defined?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback everyone. I'm going to guess the Frederick and Aetherus are correct in guessing that the culprit is `ancestors`. @spickermann, so far as I can tell I am unable to look at how the tests are defined. I can only see their output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe they don't want you to use `map` and `include?` since they are not methods of classes. They are methods of arrays.

I guess this shall pass the tests.

```
def is_ancestor?(klass, subclass)
  subclass <= klass
end
```

Well, strictly speaking, `<=` is also a method.

BTW, if you can compare classes directly, don't compare their names. You original code can be optimized as

```
def is_ancestor?(klass, subclass)
  subclass.ancestors.include? klass
end
```